# Creating a list of numpy.ndarray of unequal length in Cython

Tags: python, arrays, object, numpy, cython

I now have python code to create a list of ndarrays, and these arrays are not equal length. The piece of code snippet that looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
from mymodule import list_size, array_length # list_size and array_length are two lists of ints, and the len(array_length) == list_size

ndarray_list = []

for i in range(list_size):
    ndarray_list.append(np.zeros(array_length[i]))
```

Now, I need to convert this to Cython, but do not know how. I tried to create a 2-d dynamically allocated array, like this:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from mymodule import list_size, array_length

cdef int i
ndarray_list = <double **>malloc(list_size * sizeof(double*))
for i in range(list_size):
    ndarray_list[i] = <double *>malloc(array_length[i] * sizeof(double))
```

However, this method only creates a double pointer in ndarray_list[i]. I cannot pass it to other functions which requires some of the ndarray method.

What should I do?

Comment: I tried to condense the two approaches in one answer, but it looks much better split in two... your approach with `malloc()` is orders of magnitudes faster, so you should consider the `malloc()`-based answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to pass the C `double*` buffer to a function that requires a `numpy.ndarray` you can create a temporary buffer and assign to its memory address the address of the `double*` array.

This `malloc()`-based solution is orders of magnitude faster than the other answer based on NumPy buffers. Note how to `free()` the inner arrays to avoid a memory leak.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from cython cimport view
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef int i
cdef double test
list_size = 10
ndarray_list = <double **>malloc(list_size * sizeof(double*))
array_length = <int *>malloc(list_size * sizeof(int*))
for i in range(list_size):
    array_length[i] = i+1
    ndarray_list[i] = <double *>malloc(array_length[i] * sizeof(double))
    for j in range(array_length[i]):
        ndarray_list[i][j] = j

for i in range(list_size):
    for j in range(array_length[i]):
        test = ndarray_list[i][j]

cdef view.array buff
for i in range(list_size):
    buff = <double[:array_length[i]]>ndarray_list[i]
    print np.sum(buff)

#...

for i in range(list_size):
    free(ndarray_list[i])
free(ndarray_list)
free(array_length)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Saullo Castro for your excellent answer! Just one quick question in understanding the code - why is `buff.data` casted to `<char *>`? Shouldn't it be a `<double *>`?

Comment: @ShawnWang That was my first attempt but I got `Cannot assign type 'double *' to 'char *'`, then I used `char *`, I did not find any reference explaining why we must use `char *`

Comment: Thanks Saullo! This is really interesting... I tried `void *` and it wouldn't work either. Well, at least we got it working. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @ShawnWang I am trying to find a better way to do this... without having to call `np.empty()` and use this `char *` cast...

Comment: @ShawnWang I've found a very straightforward way to do it in a much cleaner way using Cython arrays... check the update...

Comment: Thank you so much! I am such an idiot to have forgotten that I can easily use np.mean(memory_view)... This is excellent. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `object` type with a NumPy-based buffer. To populate `ndarray_list` efficiently you only need an `object` buffer, but note that many calls to `np.zeros()` may cause some slowness:

```
cdef int i, list_size
cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] array_length
cdef np.ndarray[object, ndim=1] ndarray_list

list_size = 10000
array_length = np.arange(list_size).astype(np.int)+1

ndarray_list = np.empty(list_size, dtype=object)
for i in range(list_size):
    ndarray_list[i] = np.zeros(array_length[i], dtype=np.float64)
```

To access the inner arrays efficiently, you need another 1-D buffer:

```
cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] inner_array
cdef double test
cdef int j

for i in range(list_size):
    inner_array = ndarray_list[i]
    for j in range(inner_array.shape[0]):
        test = inner_array[j]
```